# ApexChart custom tooltip available overflow

Tags: apexcharts

I use ApexChart as well. but one i need is custom tooltip.

In my tooltip data is can be very very long. so in custom tooltip available to overflow auto.

scroll is well shown. but cannot be scrolling by user.
how can i available scrolling in custom tooltip apexcharts?